# What does it mean to be "a crofter at an ironwork"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in the short story "The Rattrap" by Selma Lagerlöf:

> The old man was just as generous with his confidences as with his porridge and tobacco. **The guest was informed at once that in his days of prosperity his host had been a crofter at Ramsjo Ironwork and had worked on the land.** Now, that he was no longer able to do day labor, it was his cow which supoprted him.

There is one more place in the chapter referencing to the crofter by saying "old crofter of the ironworks". I wanted to ask that "crofting" and "ironwork" are wholly different occupations. But why then is the author saying "crofter of/at the ironwork"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "crofter" is according the [the dictionary.com definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/crofter)

> a person who rents and works a small farm, especially in Scotland or northern England.

The [related Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crofting) says:

> Crofting is a form of land tenure and small-scale food production particular to the Scottish Highlands, the islands of Scotland, and formerly on the Isle of Man. Within the 19th century townships, individual crofts are established on the better land, and a large area of poorer-quality hill ground is shared by all the crofters of the township for grazing of their livestock.

In

> ...in his days of prosperity his host had been a crofter at Ramsjo Ironwork.

"Ramsjo Ironwork" is being used as the name of a place, where there was an iron foundry, but also an adjacent village and farms.

[[image: Seal of Ramsjö ironworks in Sweden, 18th century.]]

(Seal of Ramsjö ironworks in Sweden, 18th century.)

Comment: Good answer! Some large ironworks also provided dorms/food for their workers, so the implication could possibly be that he sold his farm goods primarily to the Ironworks or those affiliated with it.

Comment: Here is a summary of the story in English, for those interested in the context: https://skoolboye.wordpress.com/tag/crofter/